# I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException on server while debug locally it's working fine

Tags: java

I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException` on Jboss server. While debugging locally, it's working fine. I am having one PDF file which is part of the jar itself. This PDF will be send in the mail.

This jar will run on server by kjb job.

Exception is like this:-

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/adminjboss   
/bin/Kettle-3.2.0/libext/Rapi-scheduler-2.8.13_UAT.jar! 
/SupplierGuide.pdf(No such file or directory).
```

Comment: If you were to copy/paste that URI on your local machine and the server, does it find anything?

Comment: A off topic advice: In the screenshot, you have tried to hide class name and package name but they are still visible and can be read. It could be an issue for you.

Comment: That's fine. I will remove screen shot after getting solution.

Comment: No, it is not at all fine. You do not link to pictures of code. Never ever. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: And honestly, what exactly do you expect us to tell you? The exception message is super clear: that file doesn't exist on the server machine. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Why all these downvotes. A java dev should see the error... Answer below.

Comment: thanks for giving me correct guide. I have removed picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is within the jar you have to extract it, something like (untested)

```
File temp = File.createTempFile();
try(InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/SupplierGuide.pdf")) {
   IOUtils.copy(is, new FileOutputStream(temp));
}
```

If you debug locally it may function properly because you debug with an "expanded layout", i.e. you have your classes directly in the classpath.

Comment: thanks. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: this solution is work for me. thanks a lot :)

Comment: but i have one problem now. my attached file having random number. Do you know how to remove random number appended to the filename?

Comment: My final code is like this.'code' File temp =null;
        try {
            temp = File.createTempFile("SupplierGuide", ".pdf");  
            final InputStream inputStream = SendNotificationToContacts.class.getClassLoader()
                   .getResourceAsStream(result.getProperty("supplier.guide"));
            
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(temp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }'code'